# Understanding the isomorphism of Picard group with the first cohomology group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am learning the subject for the first time, and the material has not yet settled inside me. I would like to get some intuitive understanding of the following:

Let $X$ be a complex manifold. The Picard group $Pic(X)$ of $X$ is an abelian group of isomorphism classes of holomorphic line bundles on $X$. I want to first get a rough idea on why $Pic(X)$ is naturally isomorphic to the first cohomology group $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*_X)$ where $\mathcal{O}^*_X$ is the multiplicative sheaf of no-where vanishing holomorphic functions on $X$.

How should I think of this isomorphism? I want to get some understanding, without going into the technical proof. Is it possible to understand the above result without getting into Cech cohomology?

Comment: Actually the Cech Cohomology is the easier (or the easiest?) approach. If you ignore some technical details when defining Cech cohomology, the isomorphism $Pic(X) \cong H^1(X, \mathscr O^*)$ is almost immediate.

Comment: I echo John's comments. Actually, I would say it more strongly: Čech cohomology is the _best_ way of understanding this isomorphism.